# Get end date from a given start date , weekdays and number of occuring of executions

Tags: javascript

I am new to programming. I am using javascript right now. I wanted codes to get end date for a execution. I have got Startdate, weekdays(days in which execution occures) and number of executions to occure. How can i get end date???

For example Start date is '15 - 03 - 2018'
days to be executed are Sunday ie '0' and friday '5' 
Number of executions from start date to end date is 5
End date of execution here should be '30-03-2018' which is to be retrieved.

Any idea...

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: can you please give example?

Comment: Please go read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, and how to create a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done like this. I somehow figured out a method.

```
function calcDate() {
var type="weekly";
var date1=new Date('2018,mar,18');
var date2;
var gdays=[];
gdays[0]=0;
gdays[1]=1;

count=10;

if(type=="weekly"){


    var d1=date1.getDate();
    var year=date1.getFullYear();
    var month=date1.getMonth();


    while(count>0){
        var temp=[];
        var tempdays=[];

        tempdays=getDaysInMonth(month,year,d1);
        console.log(tempdays);

    for(var i=0;i<=gdays.length-1;i++) {
        var on=gdays[i];
        var ddd=days(year,month,on);
        for(var j=0;j<=ddd.length-1;j++){
            temp.push(ddd[j]);
        }

    }

    temp.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
    console.log(temp);

     for(var k=0;k<=temp.length-1;k++){
         if(tempdays.includes(temp[k])){
             var finalday=temp[k];
             count--;
             alert("count" +count);
             if(count==0) break;

         }

    } 
    if(count==0){
        alert("final day"+finalday);
    date2=new Date(year,month,finalday);
    alert(date2);
    }
    if(count>0){
        d1=0;
        month=month+1;
        if(month>11){
            month=0;
            year=year+1;
        }
    }

    }

}





function  days(year,month,on){
    var day, counter, date;
   var days=[];
    day = 1;
    counter = 0;
    date = new Date(year, month, day);
    while (date.getMonth() === month) {
        if (date.getDay() ==on) { // Sun=0, Mon=1, Tue=2, etc.
            days[counter]=date.getDate();
            counter += 1;
        }
        day += 1;
        date = new Date(year, month, day);
    }
    return(days);

    }
function getDaysInMonth(month, year,day) {
    day++;
    alert(day);
     var date = new Date(year, month, day);
     var days = [];
     while (date.getMonth() === month) {
         var i=date.getDate();
        days.push(i);
        date.setDate(date.getDate()+1);
     }
     return days;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

```js
var date = new Date(2018,2,15);  // set date to 15-Mar-2018
var weekdays = [0,6];           // set weekdays
var noOfExcution = 3;

var day = 7 - date.getDay();    //calculate first week days
noOfExcution -= weekdays.filter(x=>x>=date.getDay()).length;
day += noOfExcution % weekdays.length > 0 
      ? weekdays[noOfExcution % weekdays.length - 1] 
      : weekdays[weekdays.length-1];  //calulate last week days
var x = Math.floor((noOfExcution-0.1) / weekdays.length) * 7 +
        day;  //calculate in between dates
date.setDate(date.getDate() + x);     //setting end date

console.log(date.toLocaleString());  //printing end date
```

Comment: I made a slight change in your code and tried. var x = Math.floor((noOfExcution / weekdays.length) * 7) +
        (weekdays[noOfExcution % weekdays.length - 1] + 1); And it does not work for even number of execution at all

Comment: when change was made for odd number of cases it works fine.. but crashes for even numbers

Comment: Try noOfExcution as even numbers and weekdays = [0,2]

Comment: _var date = new Date(2018,2,15); var weekdays = [0,3]; var noOfExcution = 2;_ the expected output was **3/21/2018, 12:00:00 AM** but it is **3/18/2018, 12:00:00 AM**

Comment: @Azhar how would expected output will be **3/21/2018, 12:00:00 AM** as task will over by 18th(first will be on 15th and 2nd will be on 18th and aftere that there is no excution.)

Comment: sorry my mistake,  i forgot to tell you on the initial date ie on 15 no task will be happening it is on **18** first execution happens and **21** will be the next so **21** is expected output.

Comment: can you pls resolve for even again it does n't work for other cases in even like 4 , 6 , 8 even if it is start day is considered too

Comment: for multiple `weekdays ` too it does not provide coorect answer thanks for trying anyway

Comment: @Azhar this is last try,(hope this helps otherwise, sorry for so much of trouble)

Comment: @Azhar just do one thing,use for loop it is not best way but it will work.(it is costly)